# How to access JFrame's method from JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have my main JFrame and one more JDialog.
If user click on the button, i want JDialog to call method from this JFrame(which contains some operations on ComboBox in this JFrame).
How can I do that?
I don't want to use MyJFrame form = new MyJFrame(); because it will make a new JFrame which i don't want to do, i want to call method from JFrame which is running currently on my computer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `JButton` is on the `JDialog`.

If both are in the same class, why not just do this?

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //I just got clicked
        form.doSomething();
    }
});
```

which can be shortened to

```
button.addActionListener(e -> form.doSomething());
```

If they aren't, and you're extending `JDialog` (which I wouldn't recommend) just pass the `JFrame` in its constructor, then your dialog will have access to it.

It's not possible to add much more without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Actually... they are not. There are JFrame and JDialog in the "View" package, because program is based on MVC. It is not that easy... ;p

Comment: @Persantarus are you extending `JDialog` in your second class? Pass your `MyJFrame` in its constructor and use that

Comment: java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JDialog(form).setVisible(true);
            }
        });  <-- It gives me an error "non-static variable form cannot be referenced from a static context". I made variable private JFrame form and in constructor this.form = form;

Comment: Is this in your main method? `static` methods can't use instance variables.

Comment: Ye, it  is. Are there any other options?

Comment: When should this `Runnable` be executed? There must be a way to put this into your dialog class.

Comment: I'm making it on Netbeans so this is generated automatically. It is executed in main(bottom of the Dialog) and the code looks like I paste in upper post.

Comment: I'm not too experienced with NetBeans but there should be a way to specify what method to run when you click a button, no? If not I'd suggest writing the GUI yourself as you have much more control over it.

Comment: I did it by just deleting main method. I don't need it cause it is JDialog, not JFrame. I gave my JFrame as parameter in constructor like you said, thanks for help! :)

Comment: @Persantarus if you've solved your problem, can you accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` , show a JDialog to take input from User.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't do that. My JDialog has some ComboBoxes, TextArea and so on... It is impossible for me to make InputDialog like you said. Well... maybe it is possible, but I will have much more work on the view of this JOptionPane.